# Creating an ng-cli container in docker not working

Tags: angular, docker

I'm working with angular2 and docker and trying to build an image. when I enter 
   in  *"docker build -t angular-client:dev ."* Everything seems to work but 
   when I run the angular-client to try to create a container it starts and than 
   stops. Please can some one help me figure this out.....

```
**My dockerfile**

# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]


**My package.Json** 

 {
"name": "angular-client",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"angular-cli": {},
"scripts": {
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
"lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"test": "ng test",
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
"e2e": "protractor"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "4.0.9",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "3.13.0",
"typescript": "~2.0.3",
"webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
 }

 **The output coming from kitematic**

 npm info lifecycle angular-client@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
 npm ERR! Linux 4.4.59-boot2docker
 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
 npm ERR! node v6.10.2
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
 npm ERR! file sh
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall spawn
 npm ERR! angular-client@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the angular-client@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve --host 
 0.0.0.0'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
 installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-client 
 package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
 with:
 npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-client
 npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-client
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev dependency for Angular CLI is missing. I'm not sure this is the only issue but it will be causing the **ng serve** error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your "npm start" command is failing.
Check out  **The output coming from kitematic**, the error logs there can lead you to the problem